# Readin a .txt file and put the elements in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list

Im new in Python and i need some help. i got a .txt file in this form:

```
Time[tab]Signal

0[tab]1.05

0.5[tab]1.06

1[tab]1.09

1.5[tab]1.12
```

Now i want to read in the file. I need two lists. List1 should contain the time and list2 should contain the signal.

This is my try:

```
daten = open("extedit.txt", "r")
lines = daten.readlines();
list1 = []

for i in lines:
    list1.append(i.strip().split('\t'));
daten.close()

del list1[1]
print(list1)
```

[image: thats the form at my txt file]

Something went wrong i think.. maybe you can help me

i got this in my terminal:

`[['{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf760'], ['{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}'], ['{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}'], ['\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0'], ['\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0'], [''], ['\f0\fs24 \cf0 Zeit', 'Signal\'], ['0.01', '1.1\'], ['0.02', '1.105\'], ['0.03', '1.108\'], ['0.04', '1.2\'], ['0.05', '1.205\'], ['0.06', '1.209}']]`

Comment: are you sure that you have a txt file? It seems that you are trying to read a rtf file. Was this file modified under mac os?

Comment: You've shown us a screenshot of something that is not a text file and the contents of the file are clearly not the text file example you show. This is likely an RTF file. Can you verify that and either edit or remove this question so that you don't waste people's time?

Answer (score 1):

Change the **File_Name=** according to your needs.

```
File_Name = 'aa.txt'
time_list = []
signal_list = []
with open(File_Name,'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip() 
        time,signal = line.split()
        time = time.strip()
        signal = signal.strip()
        time_list.append(time)
        signal_list.append(signal)

print(time_list)
print(signal_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use semicolons in python!
As suspected, you are trying to read a RTF file. 
First reformat your file. I propose also an other way:

```
import csv

list1 = []
with open("extedit.txt") as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, dialect="excel-tab"):
        list1.append(line[0])

del list1[0]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a .txt file with same contents that you provided and the program you wrote prints this (multi-dimensional list):

```
[['Time', 'Signal'], ['0.5', '1.06'], ['1', '1.09'], ['1.5', '1.12']]
```

By the looks of it your file isn't actually .txt.

To answer your question:

```
del list1[1]
```

This will delete the wrong position. To delete Time/Signal line, you should do this instead:

```
del list1[0]
```

This is because items in Python lists start at positon 0.

Try this code (list comprehension):

```
daten = open("extedit.txt", "r")
lines = daten.readlines()
list1 = []
for i in lines:
    list1.append(i.strip().split('\t'));
daten.close()

del list1[0]

zeit = [i[0] for i in list1]

signal = [i[1] for i in list1]

print(zeit)
print(signal)
```