# Data extract from text file

Tags: python

Please help. 
I have data in text file with 2 long columns tab spaced
I have to extract first and second columns separately
Can it be done with Python ?

Comment: Can you add a couple of example rows?

Comment: And what you've tried so far

Comment: I tried Notepad++ and Python but couldn't implement it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Readin a .txt file and put the elements in a list (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317644/readin-a-txt-file-and-put-the-elements-in-a-list-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the columns as two separate lists:

```
first_column = []
second_column = []
data_file = open('your_file.txt')
for line in data_file.readlines():
    first_column.append(line.split('\t')[0])
    second_column.append(line.split('\t')[1])
data_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's solved

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please mark it as correct.